# QGIS symbology to ESRI

Tags: qgis, symbology, arcgis-platform

Does anybody know how to export the layer symbology from QGIS into a format that can be used by with ESRI products?

I have been successful in exporting an XML but it quotes the file type as: !DOCTYPE qgis_style. Can anybody answer whether this will import into ArcGIS developers account?

Comment: Almost everybody asks this question going the other direction (Arc to Q). The intermediate step in that conversion is almost always an SLD. A quick search on "ArcGIS import SLD" turned up a help file: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000468000000 (which may or may not help you).